# why use menu.findItem() and not findViewByID alone?

Tags: java, android

i'm new to android and have a question about the difference of this two line of code but first suppose i have a menu.xml file that contain two item in it a save item with id "save" and a delete item with id "delete"

```
MenuItem menuSave = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.save);
```

the above line won't work for me but instead this line work:

```
MenuItem menuSave = menu.findItem(R.id.save);
```

what is the difference between this two ? any why the first line give me error and won't work?

Comment: Read the doc. nothing to answer here.

Comment: i don't know why users downVote my question . I'm new to android an after some research i have this question .

Comment: they downvote because you didn't research yourself before asking. You didn't read the documentation, etc. They think that the answer is obvious.

Comment: Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: believe me . i searched the net and some documentation and found something but i didn't understand .

Comment: "why the first line give me error and won't work?" -- since you have not provided a [mcve], or even said what the error is, nobody can really help you with this. Perhaps your `Menu` does not have an item named `save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the second line refers to menu to find its item and the first finds view in activity layout

Doc for the first line: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

Doc for the second line:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)

Answer (score 1):

[findItem(R.id.save)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int)) :
    `MenuItem menuSave = menu.findItem(R.id.save);`  because  in your control in `<item>` element of your `<menu>` resource. so `menu.findItem(R.id.save);`
and it  Return the menu item with a particular identifier.

[findViewById(R.id.save)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem(int))
 Finds the first descendant view with the given ID, the view itself if the ID matches getId(), or null if the ID is invalid (< 0) or there is no matching view in the hierarchy.